# Counting files with Today's date

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to count the occurrences of files with today's date in a directory with the format 
submission.YYMMDDS.csv
…where:

YY = current year, excluding century (e.g. 17 for 2017)

MM = current month number (e.g. 07 for July)

DD = current day number within month (e.g. 21 for the 21st day of the month)

S = sequence number of file within YYMMDD, starting from 0 (e.g. 1 if the file is the 2nd file created for this value of YYMMDD)

this works:

```
ls *.csv | grep -oc  "submission.$( date +%y%m%d)"
```

BUT I'd really like to incorporate the "S.csv" in the grep (S being a wildcard sequential number)

This does not work:

```
ls *.csv | grep -oc  "submission.$( date +%y%m%d)" *.csv
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't just `grep -oc  "submission.$( date +%y%m%d)" *.csv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell is bash, given this directory and date:

```
$ ls
submission.1709043.csv  submission.1709052.csv  submission.1709053.csv
$ date
Tue Sep  5 17:26:14 CDT 2017
```

you should do:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ files=( submission.$(date +%y%m%d)[0-9]*.csv )
$ echo "${#files[@]}"
2
$ shopt -u nullglob
```

The nullglob is so you don't get a count of 1 if the directory is empty. That will work even for file names containing newlines or any other spaces.